# VLookup from Last Column in Range VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm attempting to write VBA that will VLookup information from an array on a different worksheet and return it. The issue is, my code needs to lookup the information from the last column in the range, however since the range is a pivot table and the columns are months with backlog, the number of columns may differ. The VBA is successful at putting the code into the target cell but it gets a #NAME? error so there's something getting messed up with the object declarations I believe. Can someone please assist?

```
Sub VLookupLastColumn()

Dim Row7 As Long
Dim Column1 As Long
Dim myTableArray As Range


Sheets("Pivot Values").Select
Row7 = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Column1 = Range("A" & Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
With ActiveSheet
    Set myTableArray = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Row7, Column1))
End With

Sheets("Output").Select
Range("BD5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-55],myTableArray,Column1,0)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub VLookupLastColumn()

    Dim Row7 As Long, Column1 As Long
    Dim myTableArray As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Pivot Values") 'use a worksheet variable
    
    Row7 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Column1 = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set myTableArray = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(Row7, Column1))
    
    'add countif starting at row 7
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(7, Column1 + 1), ws.Cells(Row7, Column1 + 1)).Formula = _
         "=COUNTIF(B7:" & ws.Cells(7, Column1).Address(False, False) & ","">0"")"
    
    With Sheets("Output").Range("BD5")
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & .Offset(0, -55).Address(False, False) & "," & _
                             ExtAddress(myTableArray) & "," & Column1 & ",FALSE)"
    End With

End Sub

'return a range address, including the worksheet name
Function ExtAddress(rng As Range)
    ExtAddress = "'" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Address()
End Function
```

Comment: This works, finding the last row and last column works, my table array is successful, this just pulls the VLookup from the "Output" sheet when it should be pulling the VLookup from the "Pivot Values" sheet. How would I tweak this so that it pulls the VLookup from the "Pivot Values" sheet?

Comment: My bad - I forgot to add the sheet name to the address for `myTableArray`. See update above

Comment: Thanks this fixed it! Now, a follow-up question, I want to add a =CountIf() column starting in Row 8 of the first available column, so the n+1 column of Column1, such that this column Counts all non-zero occurrences in Columns B-Column1 minus 1, so if Column1 is found to be Column E, it would be a =CountIf() of non zero occurrences in columns B-D, and then going through Row7, can you think of a way to accomplish this? I'm new at VBA and any attempt you may have would be very much appreciated!

Comment: See above - untested, but should get you started.